# parsing data from google maps api v3 with json with php

Tags: php, json, google-maps, parsing

I would like parse data from google maps geocode version 3 through json. I would like to get details like locaityName, AdministrativeAreaName and status code. May I know how to parse these data? Thank you

Comment: Man, 2 years later and still no one answered your question directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/json_decode) that will convert a JSON data stream into a PHP array or object.

Comment: I would like to parse specific data from google geocode as I mentioned above. do you know the structure of parsing these data? Thanks.

Comment: @ben why don't you just make a request and find out yourself using `print_r()`? It's the easiest way.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getGoogleAddressCoordinates()
    {
        //using the google maps api to get the long and lat coordinates of addresss
        //using form post variables
        $address =trim($_POST['address']);
        $city = trim($_POST['city']);
        $state = trim($_POST['state']);

        //formats the address add '+' into space
        $address = str_replace( ' ', '+' ,$address);
        $city = str_replace( ' ', '+', $city);
        $address = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", '+', $address ); //remove non alpha numeric chars such as extra spaces.
        $address_str = $address.',+'. $city.',+'.$state;
        $geo_url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address_str&sensor=false";
        //echo $geo_url;
        //echo file_get_contents($geo_url);
        $json_result = json_decode(file_get_contents($geo_url));

        $geo_result =  $json_result->results[0];
        $coordinates = $geo_result->geometry->location;

        //see if the it is locating the real address or just apox location, or in most cases a bad address
        if($geo_result->types[0] == 'street_address')
            $coordinates->valid_address  = TRUE;
        else
            $coordinates->valid_address  = FALSE;

        return $coordinates;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json_encode` and `json_decode` functions to parse json data.

More info:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I would like to parse specific data from google geocode as I mentioned above. do you know the structure of parsing these data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the PHP PECL json library

```
json_decode()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Just an advice, if the function doesn't return anything that means that there is a syntax error into the JSON, it will not raise any error or log.