# php $json google maps parsing

Tags: json, parsing, maps

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$q = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=35.0078,-97.0929&destinations=45.2078,-97.0929&mode=driving&sensor=false"; 

$json = file_get_contents($q); 

$details = json_decode($json, TRUE); 

echo "<pre>"; print_r($details); echo "</pre>"; 
?>
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [destination_addresses] => Array
        (
            [0] => 150th St, Summit, SD 57266, USA
        )

    [origin_addresses] => Array
        (
            [0] => 38591 Patterson Rd, Wanette, OK 74878, USA
        )

    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [elements] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [distance] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => 1,299 km
                                            [value] => 1299343
                                        )

                                    [duration] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => 13 hours 26 mins
                                            [value] => 48361
                                        )

                                    [status] => OK
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [status] => OK
)
```

I need to extract from $json only the distance (1,299 km).
I am not sure how to do this.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Seems this is a very similar question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703916/parsing-data-from-google-maps-api-v3-with-json-with-php

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php $q = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=35.0078,-97.0929&destinations=45.2078,-97.0929&mode=driving&sensor=false"; 

$json = file_get_contents($q);
$details = json_decode($json);
$distance=$details->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text;
echo $distance; ?>
```